# Getting temperature difference between intervals

Tags: php, mysql, intervals

my question is more "theoretical" than practical - in other words, Im not really looking for a particular code for how to do something, but more like an advice about how to do it. Ive been thinking about it for some time but cannot come up with some feasible solution.
So basically, I have a MySQL database that saves weather information from my weather station.

Column one contains date and time of measurement (Datetime format field), then there is a whole range of various columns like temp, humidity etc. The one I am interested in now is the one with the temperature. The data is sorted by date and time ascending, meaning the most recent value is always inserted to the end.

Now, what I want to do is using a PHP script, connect to the db and find temperature changes within a certain interval and then find the maximum. In other words, for example lets say I choose interval 3h. Then I would like to find the time, from all the values, where there was the most significant temperature change in those 3 h (or 5h, 1 day etc.).

The problem is that I dont really know how to do this. If I just get the values from the db, Im getting the values one by one, but I cant think of a way of getting a value that is lets say 3h from the current in the past. Then it would be easy, just subtracting them and get the date from the datetime field at that time, but how to get the values that are for example those 3 h apart (also, the problem is that it cannot just simply be a particular number of rows to the past as the intervals of data save are not regular and range between 5-10mins, so 3 h in the past could be various number of rows).

Any ideas how this could be done?

Thx alot

Comment: Hm, given that there are now 2 answers that answer different questions, perhaps some clarification is in order: do you need (a) the max temperature as in the other answer (b) the maximum change relative to the previous measurement as in my answer (c) just the max range (`MAX() - MIN()`), (d) the biggest _consecutive_ changes (multiple records with either all minus or plus offset in a row) or (e) something different?

Comment: Or like (f) given the _whole_ dataset, which interval N has the highest total difference, or (g) given the _whole_ dataset, which interval has the highest difference between 2 consecutive records?

Comment: Ok I will try to explain, sorry Im not a native speaker.

Comment: So the best way, lets say just an example:
Time 1 - temp 10C
Time 2 - temp 12C
Time 3 - temp 14C
Time 4 - temp 13C
Time 5 - temp 16C

Now lets assume there are 1h differences in the times, than I would like to scan the whole db and find the biggest change in T within lets say that 1h, in this case it would be 3C in the last time interval. So I would like the result to be the start and end time + the actual change value

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly hard actually. So I would assume it's a two column table with `time` and `temp` fields, where `time` is a DATETIME field

```
SELECT MAX(temp) FROM records
WHERE time >= "2013-10-14 12:00:00" and time <= "2013-10-14 15:00:00"
```

Comment: Thx, but Im afraid you misunderstood the question. I want to scan the whole database and find the biggest temperature change (not the actual temp value) within those 3h - in other words, find the time in the entire db history, where there was the most rapid change in temperature

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, ABS(t1.temperature - t2.temperature) as change
FROM  tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2
    ON  t2.timecolumn <= (t1.timecolumn - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
LEFT JOIN tablename t3
    ON  t3.timecolumn <= (t1.timecolumn - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    AND t2.timecolumn > t3.timecolumn
WHERE 
  t3.some_non_nullable_column IS NULL
ORDER BY ABS(t1.temperature - t2.temperature) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

1 table joined 2 times on itself, <del>t2 is the quaranteed direct predecessor of t1</del> t2 is the closest record with offset 3h before *or more*. This could with the proper indexes, and a limited amount of data (where limited is in the eye of the beholder) be quite performant. *However*, if you need a lot of those queries in a big dataset, this is a prime candidate for *denormalization*, were you create a table which also stores the calculated offsets compared to the previous entry.

Comment: This is not what he wants. He doesn't want the temperature change between readings but between intervals (which may be supplied by an argument - 3 hours in his example). Between the interval there may be many readings since the time between readings vary randomly from 5 minutes to 10 minutes. For example, the first row of the diff subtracts the first and 18th temperature, the second row of the diff subtracts the second and 23rd etc.

Comment: thats what I thought about too, to actually add another column, but the problem is that this would be relatively easy to do, just tell him to add a value that is 3 h ago and then I would have both temps on the same row, but the problem is that this would first of all increase the db size and second, more important, limit me to use it only to time intervals that are in the columns in the db and if I wanted to use lets say 6h instead this would be useless, thats why I am trying to avoid this and do it purely by a script.
And in terms of the size, it is a big db, currently around 200k rows.

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for the most rapid change in temperature within a particular time interval from the whole db.

Comment: Well, then this answer is indeed not it :) I'll delete it in a moment, but as you have irregular intervals, you might want to elaborate more on how you would treat tie-breaks in intervals (say you choose 3h, we can do only 2h55 of 3h05, which to choose?)

Comment: That would in my opinion not be such a problem I could use 
datetime_field - interval 3 hour

Comment: Hm, something came to me, this would be more in accordance with @siebetman's explanation, but it has the drawback of finding the record ON, or MORE then the interval (you may want 'closest one' instead, which could be LESS then the interval).

Comment: Hah, indeed, that `JOIN` on (`time - INTERVAL ...`) is what could be done here (with the mentioned drawback).